# Error with cycle For and requests Python3 Parsing

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

#s = Session()

def get_photo_from_page():
    tut = []
    r = requests.get('https://vk.com/uporols_you').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    im = soup.find_all('img', class_="ph_img")
    for a in im:
        s = a.get('data-src_big').split('|')[0]
        tut.append(s)
    y = "img%s.jpg"
    for t, im in tut, [y % i for i in range(1,5)]:
        p = requests.get(t)
        out = open(im, "wb")
        out.write(p.content)
        out.close()

def main():
    get_photo_from_page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> error from cmd   for t, im in tut, [y % i for i in range(1,5)]:
>   ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>   **> I need to list with a 1 to 1 accrue to URL, and on passage possylke,
>   and save all images with the new name, in separate cycles, it always
>   takes the last available reference and stores it as the number of
>   times indicated in the cycle.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

#s = Session()

def get_photo_from_page():
    tut = []
    r = requests.get('https://m.vk.com/uporols_you').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
    im = soup.find_all('img', class_="ph_img")
    try:
        for a in im:
            s = a.get('data-src_big').split('|')[0]
            tut.append(s)
        print(tut)  
    except:
        print('no have any links)')

    for num, link in enumerate(tut, start=1):
        p = requests.get(link)
        out = open("img%s.jpg" % (num), 'wb')
        out.write(p.content)
        out.close()

def main():
    get_photo_from_page()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```